# Does this catch all phone number formats?

Tags: javascript, regex

I've been working on code to convert user input into a readable form of a phone number.  I am not scrubbing anything when the user inputs a phone number, but I do try to scrub it on output back to the screen.  Below is my helper function that I'm using.  Does anyone see a case that this does not catch?

```
var formatPhone = function(raw){
  var parts = raw.replace(/[^0-9X]/gi, '').split('x');
  var result = parts[0];
  switch(result.length){
    case(13):
      result = result.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/, '+$1 ($2) $3-$4');
      break;
    case(12):
      result = result.replace(/(\d{2})(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/, '+$1 ($2) $3-$4');
      break;
    case(11):
      result = result.replace(/(\d{1})(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/, '$1 ($2) $3-$4');
      break;
    case(10):
      result = result.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/, '($1)v$2-$3');
      break;
    case(7):
      result = result.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{4})/, '$1-$2');
      break;
    default:
      result = result;
  }
  if(parts.length>1){
    result += ' ext ' + parts[1];
  }
  return new Handlebars.SafeString(result);
};
```

General explanation of the code:

1. Use an inverted regular express to strip all characters except 0-9
   and Xx
2. Split the string based upon Xx
3. Take the first part and based on its length calculate the output
   format

   - For 12&13 character strings (assumed international) prepend a +
   - For 11 character strings use n (nnn) nnn-nnnn
   - For 10 characters use (nnn) nnn-nnnn
   - For 7 characters use nnn-nnnn
   - For all other character lengths just output it
4. Next if there is a 2nd part to the parts array append ext and the
   rest

Sound about right?  Should I catch for ; or other special characters as well?

Comment: Perfect question hate to see this closed!

Comment: I thought so too, but apparently I was overruled by the admins :(